# Which real-life celebrities has Superman fought?

Tags: dc, comics, superman

Recently I discovered that Superman once fought Muhammad Ali, at least according to the image below. Now I'm wondering what other real-world celebrities he's battled against. I'd also like to know the outcomes of those fights, and the reasons behind them (including this one).

[image]

Comment: Are people saying that there are too many answers? Too loose a definition of "celebrities"?

Comment: somebody could ask an identification question about the various celebrity spectators depicted on the cover. I spot at least half a dozen

Comment: @NKCampbell: http://www.supermantv.net/articles/ali.htm

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: Is there anything more I can add to my answer to make it more acceptable to you?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No. Your answer is great. I used to be really quick to accept answers, then I got shit for being too quick. So now I wait for a while before going back and accepting lots at once. I'll hook you up though since you asked so nicely. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Off hand:

- [Muhammad Ali](http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-story-behind-that-superman-and-muhammad-ali-team-up-1780537584) - "The issue featured an alien race named the Scrubb demanding to fight Earth’s greatest champion. Muhammad Ali and Superman each step forward to take up the challenge to save Earth. When Ali argues that Superman isn’t a proper champion of Earth, the Scrubb leader, Rat’Lar, has them fight one another on the planet Bodace (where Superman’s powers are negated)."
   Ali won.
- [Perry Como](https://babblingsaboutdccomics3.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/superman-67-lois-lane-falls-for-perry-como/) - Romantic rivalry. Como actually comes to Superman and asks for help because Lois is acting crazy. The situation is resolved when Lois's cold clears up, which results in her no longer being able to sing, and somehow thereby getting over the crush.
- [Pat Boone](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman%27s_Girlfriend,_Lois_Lane_Vol_1_9) - Had to prevent him from singing a song that would endanger Superman's secret identity, namely because the lyrics were written by Clark Kent, who accidentally spelled his name out in the first letter of each line. Settled amicably when Superman explained to Pat the situation and they worked together to present a version with new lyrics.
- [Antonino Rocca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonino_Rocca) - They fought on the cover of [Superman No. 155 (August 1962)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_155). Rocca won.

  > Famous wrestler Antonino Rocca has come to Metropolis to put on a charity match for the city, wherein he will go in the ring against Superman. Interviewing Rocca is Clark Kent and Jimmy Olsen. When Rocca demonstrates some wrestling moves, Clark agrees to be his partner, and hams up his routine of being a weakling by pretending to be overpowered by Rocca and feigning injury after.
  > That night at the match, Superman arrives and to everyone's surprise Rocca manages to toss the Man of Steel out of the ring. Everyone is shocked by Rocca's sudden increased strength when Mr. Mxyzptlk appears and claims to have been responsible for giving Rocca super-strength....

Comment: Two actual fights, two musical conflicts. We'll ignore the Donovan situation...

Comment: What's the *Donovan situation*?

Comment: There's a running joke online that Donovan and Superman have a beef due to Donovan's famous song, "Sunshine Superman". "Superman and Green Lantern ain't got nothing on me" according to Donovan's lyrics. :-D

Comment: Batman is bound to have something on him, though.

Comment: How was Lois acting "crazy"?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: Oh, just the usual stalkerish boy-crazy thing. Take a look at https://babblingsaboutdccomics3.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/sup_67_003.png for that and Perry Como and Superman mutually admiring each other.

Comment: "Mutually admiring" seems to be an understatement